# Make Brackets.io look as Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, adobe-brackets

I am trying out Brackets.io, but it looks much worse than Sublime on my screen (Apple 27"). The font/text (tried many different) is not as sharp and "fat" as it is in Sublime Text. Is there a way to make it look more like Sublime?

(I wonder if Brackets is optimized for retina displays (?), and not "ordinary" displays.)

See the attached image (Brackets.io on top, Sublime Text 2 under):

[image]

Comment: Not sure completely if there is a duplicate of that theme, but all the themes can be found https://github.com/Brackets-Themes?tab=repositories for brackets try some out

Comment: Yes, I'm using a "Sublime Text" theme in brackets.io, but it does not seem to help much (it only changes the color).

Comment: As ant said dark soda is a replica of sublime except its weird black background. You can change the background color in .css file of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Brackets font using the *View > Theme* settings box. Sublime defaults to "Consolas" on Windows, and "Menlo Regular" on Mac -- so one of those may provide a closer match.

You can also try [writing a simple Brackets extension](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-write-extensions) that introduces this CSS tweak:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";
    var ExtensionUtils = brackets.getModule("utils/ExtensionUtils");

    ExtensionUtils.addEmbeddedStyleSheet("body { -webkit-font-smoothing: auto !important; }");
});
```

That will make the font weight feel a *lot* heavier.

Answer (score 0):

The theme DarkSoda gives you the same colors as sublime text content but the background is closer to black in that. [DarkSoda Github theme and demo](https://github.com/Brackets-Themes/DarkSoda)